# Retrofit - Not sending network call when app is closed/background

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 with OkHttp. Everything is working fine with it except the one thing - a network call when app is closed or in background.

**Working**

Whenever Firebase notification arrives, I make a network call to fetch data related to that notification and then show notification.

**Scenario**

Consider an Android app which is in the background or closed and notification arrived.

**What's Happening**

Notification arrives successfully, I can see it. But when I try to make a call, it is always giving an error `Failed to connect to: *******` and I can't see any call coming on the server.

I have seen some similar type of issues, but none of them could help me.
Here's a list:

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1771
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1037
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1792

Some suggested to use `connectionPool` and some to use `pingInterval`. Nothing worked in my case. I am not sure if it's a bug of Retrofit or OkHttp.

Below is the piece of code I am using for the call. Remember that it's working perfectly fine when app is in foreground.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = getHttpBuilder()
        .connectionSpecs(getSpecList());

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Session.getBaseUrl())
        .client(builder.build())
        .build();


Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofit
        .create(Webservice.class)
        .pullNotify(authToken, ivB64, digest, Session.getTimestamp());
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        listener.onNetworkCallSuccess(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        listener.onNetworkCallFailure(t);
    }
});
```

It always returns `SocketTimeoutException`. Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure, but you can test

```
var GLOBAL_CONNECTION_POOL = ConnectionPool(5, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
private fun createClient(): OkHttpClient? {
        try {
            val trustAllManager = object : X509TrustManager {
                override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}

                override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                    return arrayOf()
                }
            }
            val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(trustAllManager)

            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
            val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

            val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            builder.followRedirects(false)
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllManager)
            builder.hostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true }
            builder.readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            builder.connectionPool(GLOBAL_CONNECTION_POOL)
            builder.addInterceptor(logging)

            return builder.build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return null
    }
```

and change:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Session.getBaseUrl())
    .client(createClient())
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using these. Difference is just that I am using `TSL` instead of `SSL` and it's common for all. Even for this current call which is only being failed when app is in background.

Comment: You can test to with RxJava, I also call api in background and app closed, but It work normal

Comment: have you fixed the problem ? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To activate some events in the background, you need to use services.
It can be done by using forground service or background service.
Forground service: https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/

check: Work manager, Alarm manager also